# continuous function on compact set, can be approximated by polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

show that if $f$ is homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ onto itself, then there is a sequence of polynomials $P_n(x)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, such that $P_n$ converge to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ and each $P_n$ is homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ onto itself.

Comment: This question is phrased in the language appropriate for assigning homework.  That is frowned on here, partly because it means you may be passing on to us a question that may have been written by someone other than yourself and that you haven't shown you understand, rather than asking your own question.

Comment: Have you studied the Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: Hi, I can do the first part using Weierstrass approx but I am confused on second part, there each polynomials are homeomorphism?

Comment: @Mathmo123: But I think this is a little stronger: we need each polynomial to be a self-homeomorphism, which is stronger than Weirstrass alone.

Comment: @rrs: There is an actual algorithm to derive the approximating polynomials to a given function.

Comment: ok, I am trying to do, thank you

Comment: @rrs: Check out the "approximating continuous functions" section in :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial Maybe you can show for a homeomorphism, all approximating polynomials are themselves homeomorphisms.

Comment: there, it does not mentioned about homeomorphism.

Comment: Note that any injective function from $[0,1]$ to itself is strictly monotone, and note that a strictly monotone polynomial is a homeomorphism (it is trivially continuous, it has an inverse because it is strictly monotone, and its inverse is continuous because it is actually differentiable by the inverse function theorem). So can you adapt the Weierstrass theorem to produce a strictly monotone polynomial, given a strictly monotone function?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881296/show-that-there-is-sequence-of-homeomorphism-polynomials-on-0-1-that-coverge-u?noredirect=1#comment1819521_881296