# Show that there is sequence of homeomorphism polynomials on [0,1] that converge uniformly to homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a homeomorphism. Show that , there exists a sequence of polynomials  $$(P_n(x))_n$$ such that $P_n(x)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$ and every $P_n(x)$ is a homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to itself.

I think that if we put additional condition that f be $C^1$ then $f'$ will be non-negative and continuous. Moreover, Weierstrass theorem says that there will be exist non-negative sequence of polynomials $(Q_n(x))_n$ such that it converges uniformly to $f'$ on $[0.1]$. Now it seems that $$P_n(x)=\int_{\mathbb{0}}^{x}Q_n(t)\:dt$$ works .

Is this true ? Is there other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[0,1]$, a theorem from Weirstrass (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) ensures that there exist a sequence of polynomials $(P_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. The sequence $(P_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ can be constructed from $f$ using the Bernstein polynomials (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial). I am not sure but I think this sequence of polynomials will do the job here.

Comment: @jibounet It won't. There's no way to guarantee those polynomials are homeomorphisms from $[0,1]$ to itself.

Comment: @Potato : Sorry! I guess my idea was too naive.

Comment: Some stuff seems to be missing in your post. Is the sequence $(P_n)$ supposed to converge to $f$? You wrote that $Q_n$'s converge uniformly. Did you mean that they converge to $f'$?

Comment: A continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ is a homeomorphism - [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism). So it would be enough to find polynomials that are bijective.

Comment: $f'$ can easily be negative. Take $f(x)=1-x$.

Comment: @Martin Sleiziak : yes exactly. i edited.

Comment: This was asked before, but received no answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846444/continuous-function-on-compact-set-can-be-approximated-by-polynomial

Comment: @MartinSleziak: yes exactly it would be enough to find polynomials that are bijective.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: When f is homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to itself it is monotonic function so $f'$ is non-negetive or non-positive. so  Without loss of generality we can think f is monotonically increasing, because else $-f$ is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. You can reduce the problem to approximating by $C^1$ homeomorphisms. Indeed, you can do it with $C^\infty$ ones. A geometer would just say to pick $n$ inputs and take any diffeomorphism agreeing with $f$ at these. I'm not sure what the technical details are in justifying such a function always exists, though.

Comment: @Potato It won't work as stated, but surely it will work if the $Q_n$ are properly rescaled so that the image is $[0,1]$ (the scaling factor will tend to $1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can show the result along the lines you sketched. First, we note that it suffices to consider monotonically increasing $f$, for the transformation $g \mapsto 1-g$ is an isometry that preserves polynomials.

Now we need to approximate the homeomorphism $f$ by continuously differentiable homeomorphisms. For that, extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by setting

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) &, x \in [0,1] \\ x &, x \notin [0,1].\end{cases}$$

Further, let $\varphi$ be a non-negative even smooth function with compact support and $\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x)\,dx = 1$. Convoloution yields a family

$$g_\eta(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x-\eta y)\varphi(y)\,dy$$

of strictly increasing smooth functions converging uniformly to $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for $\eta \searrow 0$, with $g_\eta(x) = x$ for $x \leqslant -\eta K$ or $x \geqslant 1+\eta K$ if the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $[-K,K]$.

Given $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, choose $\eta > 0$ so small that $\lvert g_\eta(x)-g(x)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{10}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then

$$h(x) = \frac{g_\eta(x) - g_\eta(0)}{g_\eta(1) - g_\eta(0)}$$

defines a smooth homeomorphism of $[0,1]$. We have

$$\begin{align}
\lvert g_\eta(x) - h(x)\rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{g_\eta(x)(g_\eta(1)-g_\eta(0)) - (g_\eta(x)-g_\eta(0))}{g_\eta(1)-g_\eta(0)}\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \frac{\lvert g_\eta(x)\rvert\cdot\lvert g_\eta(1)-1\rvert + \lvert g_\eta(0)\rvert\cdot \lvert 1-g_\eta(x)\rvert}{g_\eta(1)-g_\eta(0)}\\
&\leqslant 2\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\frac{1+\frac{\varepsilon}{10}}{1-2\frac{\varepsilon}{10}}\\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{4},
\end{align}$$

so $\lvert g(x) - h(x)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Now, since $h$ is smooth and strictly increasing, $h'$ is continuous and strictly positive, hence you can uniformly approximate $h'$ by positive polynomials. If $Q$ is a positive polynomial such that $\lvert Q(x)-h'(x)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{5}$ for $x\in [0,1]$, and $P(x) = \int_0^x Q(t)\,dt$, then $P$ is a strictly increasing (on $[0,1]$) polynomial with $\lvert P(x) - h(x)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{5}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $R(x) = \frac{P(x)}{P(1)}$ is a polynomial homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ with

$$\lvert P(x) - R(x)\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{P(x)(P(1)-1)}{P(1)}\right\rvert\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{5}\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\varepsilon}{5}}{1-\frac{\varepsilon}{5}} < \frac{\varepsilon}{4},$$

so

$$\lvert f(x) - R(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(x) - h(x)\rvert + \lvert h(x) - P(x)\rvert + \lvert P(x) - R(x)\rvert < \varepsilon.$$